# NUnit 3 test not using parameters in testcase source

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm attempting to use NUnit 3 to write a test that takes a list of double[] and tests the return of an extension method. But I can't get the test to take the testcasedata as parameters. It always runs once with a null parameter.

I've copied the example in the wiki almost exactly so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm coming from nunit 2.6 so not used to the new way of doing things. So it's probably something very obvious.

Any help appreciated.

```
[TestFixture]
public class DoubleExtensionsTest
{
    [Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(DoubleExtensionsTestData), "CoordinatesData")]
    public bool IsValidCoordinatesWorksCorrectly(double[] values)
    {
        return values.IsValidCoordinates();
    }

}

public class DoubleExtensionsTestData
{
    public static IEnumerable CoordinatesData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { 51.441860d, -0.066243d }).Returns(true);
            yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { 48.856614d, 2.352222d }).Returns(true);
            yield return new TestCaseData(new[] { -1.292066d, 36.821946d }).Returns(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running your tests? Have you tried the console? Older versions of R# or very old NUnit adapter will run tests incorrectly. Try the new NUnit 3 Visual Studio adapter.

Comment: think you're right - using testdriven.net which doesn't seem to support 3.0. That'll be it! Thanks.

Comment: TestDriven.net does support NUnit 3, you need to install the NUnitTDNet NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older 3rdParty runners such as Resharper, very old NUnit 2 Visual Studio adapters and others do not run NUnit 3 tests correctly. The symptoms are usually things like `OneTimeSetup` not getting run, or in this case, `TestCaseSource` not getting applied. Even more onerous are false positives that you will never see.

Whenever checking the behaviour of your tests, you should **always run your tests with the runner that ships with the test framework**, in this case `nunit3-console.exe`. That will tell you if it is a problem with your tests, or with your selected runner.

In this case, the tests were being run using TestDriven.NET which requires that you install the [NUnitTDNet NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTDNet/) to run NUnit 3 tests correctly.

An other option is the [NUnit 3 Test Adapter for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d).